# git - discard previous commit, force push to remote

Tags: git, commit

I will explain my situation first:

I had one file `script` in my newly created repository.

Then I did:

```
git add script
git commit -m 'initial commit'

git push -u origin master
```

..but then I realized I want comment-stripped version of my `script` file,
so I did:

-- removed comments from my `script` using `sed`

```
git rm script
git add script-no-comments
```

which git recognized as file being renamed, which is ok.

,then:

```
git commit -am 'comments removed'

git push origin master
```

So now I have locally and on remote, two commits, first being file with
comments, and another one without.

My question is: how can I now remove that first commit locally, keeping my
last version with no comments, and then I suppose I could do force-push to
remote thus overwriting commits there. I am not concerned in commit `sha`
changes, as no one will `pull` but me?

Also would that remove that comment
version for good, because I wouldn't like it to be recoverable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "remove" the first commit, but you can just squash the two commits you've made into a single commit.

You can accomplish this with a `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, but I personally find this process easier:

Move you branch pointer back to the first commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

Stage the changes from the previous commit:

```
git merge --squash HEAD@{1}
```

Commit your changes, amending them into a single commit.

```
git commit --amend
```

Force-push your new single commit to the server:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: after `git merge --squash ...` I get the message `nothing to squash, already up-to-date`

Comment: @branquito  Sorry, `HEAD@{1}`, not `{0}`.

Comment: Does this permanently remove first version of `script`, so it is not recoverable by any means, if someone would try to do that?

Comment: No; you've pushed that commit to the server, and it'll stay there until Git decides to garbage collect it, typically in ~2 weeks. Nobody will gain access to that commit unless they specifically go hunting for it though. If this is an actual *security* issue, you should look at one of the thousands of existing resources for scrubbing sensitive data out of a Git repository after it's been accidentally committed and pushed. This is a *very* well covered topic.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an interactive `rebase`, squashing the two commits:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Follow the instructions in the editor where you can also change the commit message.

The original commits still exist (but aren't reachable), you can remove them by garbage collection:

```
git gc
```